# Mongoose unique results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm looking to form a query that will pull a set of results from my mongo database, but remove/ignore results that have a duplicate field value.

Here is the senario, i'm pulling many results from the spotify api and storing them in my database, and due to the nature of what I am doing, I end up pulling many of the same albums, these albums share an `id` field. Note this is not the mongo `_id` field.

What I want, is to eliminate pulling multiple of the same album when the user builds a query that could include these duplicates.

Here is my query currently, which does what i want, but doesn't filter out the duplicates:

```
Albums.aggregate([
    { $match : { source_region : { $in: countries }}},
    { $skip  : offset },
    { $limit : limit }
])
```

At first i was using the more typical `Collection.find().sort()` etc and came across `distinct`, but you can't use `sort`, `limit` etc with `distinct`.

I've also tried using `$group` but that seems to just return the field i specify, so when i try something like:

```
{ $group : { _id : null, uniqueValues : { $addToSet : "$id" }}}
```

the only field that is returned is the `id` field, when i need about 10-20 associated with that album.

If anybody could point me in the right direction that would be great!

**Update 1**

Here is an example of some documents in the collection

```
{
  _id : ObjectId("5ad965a8bc349952904f7f31"),
  id : 0nEsaNZGpk0HIgY3OGCyR6,
  title : "some album",
  artist : "some artist
},
{
  _id : ObjectId("665fhFHJFjdjfud7d6f6"),
  id : 5JUSBHF&55sdfhjkf86sd,
  title : "another album",
  artist : "another artist
},
{
  _id : ObjectId("56&DFHJFHJJFJSgh76sdghhsd"),
  id : 0nEsaNZGpk0HIgY3OGCyR6,
  title : "some album",
  artist : "some artist
}
```

So if this was my data, I would want to only return one of the documents that share the spotify generated `id` field.

Comment: You clearly need an explanation. What exactly makes the "document" **unique** then? I see `$id` here instead of `$_id`, but is that the only field? And what to do with other things which are "duplicates".

Comment: Yeah you need to explain more than you have. So I'm prompting you to add a better explanation  to your question. Also you probably need to refresh the page and read the comment again, since you seem to be only responding partially.

Comment: ahh yeah i didn't see your revised comment. I updated the question with an example senario. To your first comment, the `id` field is generated by spotify, and that is the field i want to test against for documents be duplicates. It is separate from the mongo generated `_id` field, which is already unique.

Comment: 1 second too late. Wait while I read and if the answer needs any adjustment by your content, then I'll add it. One thing though, Mongoose treats `_id` and `id` as the same thing. MongoDB see's them as different, but you're going to have problems with mongoose if you leave it named like that.

Comment: ahhh good to know! I was thinking about changing `id` just for clarity but now i definitely will.

Comment: In reality if you really have "full duplicates", you would be better served by manipulating your "spotify" feed to rename it's `id` property to `_id`, unless you really need an `ObjectId` for other purposes. And probably could read up on "upserts" as well. Which would also help avoid the duplication. Of course, I really don't know if the duplicates are intentional or by accident.

Comment: Is it needed that same Spotify response objects get inserted multiple times. If you can avoid that in the first place, you won't have this problem.

Comment: yeah, it's a necessary evil to display results properly. the whole DB get's wiped out and refreshed every 12 hours, and the script pulls 500 results from applicable countries so it's not like the database will grow and grow with all these dupes, its more of a cache so i don't have to always make api requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've gone pretty silent, we'll just have to make some presumptions then.

With no other data to go on other than you expect "one" property in your documents to define "unique" ( other than `_id`, which already does ) then what you would do is something like this:

```
Albumns.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$uniqueProp",
    "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$doc" } }
  { "$skip": offset },
  { "$limit": limit }
])
```

Or whatever other manipulation you want to do.

With a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage, the `_id` property is what determines "uniqueness" of results that you "group by". There is never more than 1 of the same value produced by whatever gets specified in this key. You can even have a compound value:

```
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "firstField": "$firstField", "secondField": "$secondField" },
    "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
  }}
```

So whatever is in there comes out **unique**.

Whenever you are "grouping" you need an "accumulator" for anything other than the `_id` key. So here we use [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) to simply take the first result of any value we specify and use `$$ROOT` here for the whole document.

Modern releases have [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to clean up the document. If you don't have that, then you can either [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) every field or simply use the output under the `"doc"` property.

Comment: finally got time to work this in, and it works great! The only issue seems to be that because of the skip and limiting, it only makes the returned results unique, in my case, 20 at a time. So duplicates still show up as you page through the results on the frontend. I took off limit and skip and got a proper unique set though, so i think i'm just going to have to figure out a different way to achieve what i am looking for. Thanks for the concise answer!